# rz fail over expect auto login ssh

Tags: ssh, expect

I use securecrt or xshell .

```
1. use securecrt or xshell login server.
2. rz -bye      # upload file succ
3. gohost 127.0.0.1     # login one server or other server
4. rz -bye      # upload fail
```

my `gohost` code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set password "mypasswd"
set timeout 10

spawn ssh $ip
expect {
    "*yes/no" { send "yes\r"; exp_continue}
    "*assword:" { send "$password\r" }
}
interact
```

but if ssh login, manual type password(without expect auto login), it is succ.

How should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I find one server can rz succ.

so I compare two server linux env.

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US
```

use this, the server can rz upload file succ